# Purview - error (3805) connector exception connection to the database

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-purview

**Question**: When doing a [Purview scan on Azure Databricks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-azure-databricks), I get the following error. What could be the cause of the error and how we can fix it?

**Remarks**: For safety, I have replaced the 16 digits in the error with `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`. Also we have Java [JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java11) installed on the server hosting the `Integration Runtime`

> Error: (3805) Connector Exception: Connection to the database (with URL jdbc:databricks://adb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.11.azuredatabricks.net:443/default;transportMode=http;ssl=1;httpPath=sql/protocolv1/o/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/0455-165046-lamas36;AuthMech=3) failed: [Databricks]DatabricksJDBCDriver Communication link failure. Failed to connect to server. Reason: HTTP Response code: 403, Error message: Unknown. [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/troubleshoot-connections?wt.mc_id=mspurview_inproduct_learnmoreerrorlinks_troubleshootscanconnection_csadai).

Answer (score 0):

403 error means that your identity for which you generated the personal access token (PAT) doesn't have sufficient permissions to access the given SQL Warehouse.  Adjust permissions to it.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried the similar thong from my environment, and it got scanned successfully.**

[image]

While researching about the error I found out that the cause of error is **Wrong Personal Access token (PAT) is using in the credential** I was able to repro the error.

**The cause of error can be:**

- Wrong Personal Access token (PAT) using in credential.
- Expired Personal Access token (PAT).

**The resolution is to use valid Personal Access token (PAT) in credentials:**

- Create appropriate Personal Access token (PAT) to access azure databricks and copy it as shown below.
  [image]
- Add that token in keyvault and use it in credential as below.
  [image]
- Create a new credential with above secret.
  [image]
- Use it in credential.
  [image]

**Successfully scanned:**
[image]